# 1960's home.. What is this?

Tags: receptacle, kitchens

So this is above my cabinets in the kitchen, almost touching the ceiling. What is this?

[image]

Comment: Though come to think of it, these old clock receptacles would be ideal spots for WiFi hotspots!

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact, I wish it wasn't in the kitchen, would be incredible.

Comment: Side note: I was part of a campus construction project in the late 90s and we were still installing clock outlets then. It's the last time I've seen them in new construction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An older ungrounded clock outlet/receptacle.  You plugged an electric wall clock into it.

Comment: Thank you, so I am ok on patching it up as I don't plan on having a clock there.

Comment: You need to make sure there are no live wires, *including wires that are still connected to a breaker or fuse but with the breaker/fuse "off". If there are no wires - or the wires are *disconnected* on the other end, then you can close it up.

Comment: @Semir  If by patching you mean covering it up, then no unless you disconnect the wires at the junction box or the panel.  You cannot hide live(power) boxes.